# Find number of Unique Values per Item in Column B

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I have a Column B with `part number`s. These may repeat and can occur in the same warehouse, (Column A) and also different warehouses. I want to find the amount of times any particular `part number` appears in a unique warehouse.

I have tried a PivotTable and do not know if I need a macro or just a formula.

How might I achieve this?

Comment: So the pivot can count the amount of occurances column B has to a corresponding A. However if the value in A has the same value I want that to only count as one.

Comment: I have tried filtering advanced but maybe it just being early I am missing something. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I think Remove Duplicates and Filter Advanced may not be your best bet. But as I understand your requirement a PT should suit:

[image: SO21433957 example]

Comment: I wish I could paste my screenshot like that. I tried to replicate but mine isnt coming out the wat you have it. I have part # above whse because I want to find based on each part number how many unique warehouses. This is definitely the right track. Thanks:).

Comment: I havent finished completely but I know I can get on the right track after this!! Anyways its obvious you're a great help, gotta recgonize that.

Comment: pnuts, how do I make the pivot 3 columns instead of 1. And that picture will show you that unique isnt an option :)
Thanks in advanced